# Robots.txt error "Crawl postponed because robots.txt was inaccessible" from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, error

On the *robots.txt* fetch tab there is a yellow triangle when hovered over. I am getting the following message. 
"Crawl postponed because *robots.txt* was inaccessible"
However I am showing 0/151 Errors/attempts.

I use the same *robots.txt* on other sites and there is no problem.

```
www.dtnmgt.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: When did Google WMT last fetch your robots.txt and when was it last modified. Google may take 24-48 hours or so to update it's last fetch of your robots.txt.

Comment: The errors popped up on the 13th but we have had 3 successful fetches since then. The most recent on the 20th

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, your robots.txt is accessible fine - I think it's just a warning and that there was probably a disruption to the last crawl for whatever reason.

Comment: Try fetching your robots.txt as Googlebot within Google WMT as well just to make sure it is able to access it without issues.

Comment: Yep. Everything works fine. I will let it sit for a couple days

Comment: Okay great, provide an update if any further issues. I've added my comments as an answer as well now.

Answer (score 1):

Checked out the `robots.txt` and there were no issues. Your robots.txt is accessible fine - I think it's just a warning and that there was probably a disruption to the last crawl for whatever reason.

Try fetching your robots.txt as Googlebot within Google WMT as well just to make sure it is able to access it without issues.